# Slowly working word counter

Tags: strings, ruby, io, time-limit-exceeded

I have a problem where, given *N* terms, the task is to find the *k* most frequent terms from given N terms. My code is correct, but I have a time limit 10 seconds and my code doesn't pass.

Constraints:

- \$0 < N < 300000\$
- \$0 < \textrm{term length} < 25\$

```
N = gets.to_i

if N < 300000 and N
  a=[]

  (0...N).each do |i|
    el = gets
    el_size = el.length
    if el_size < 25 and el_size
      a << el
    end
    i+=1
  end

  k = gets.to_i

  new_array = {}
  size = a.length
  count = 0

  (0..size).each do |i|
    (0..size).each do |j| count += 1 if a[i] == a[j] end
    new_array[a[i]] = count
    count = 0
  end

  s_l = new_array.to_a.sort{|a, b| (b.last > a.last) ? 1 : (b.last < a.last ? -1 : (a.first <=> b.first)) }

  i = 0
  for key, val in s_l
    puts key if i < k
    i += 1
  end
end
```

And how can I print only key of hash? Currently I use `for key, val in hash`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is slow because you aren't using data structures effectively.  In particular, the nested `(0..size).each` loops will cause it to take \$O(N^2)\$ time, which will be very problematic for large \$N\$.

You created `new_array` (which is actually a hash, not an array as the name suggests), but populate it the hard way.  The easy way is to loop once through all of the words; for each word you encounter, increment its count by 1.  There is no need to construct the intermediate array `a`.

```
# Read N, then count occurrences of the next N lines of text
word_counter = Hash.new { |count, word| count[word] = 0 }
n_lines = gets.to_i
n_lines.times { word_counter[gets] += 1 }

# Read k; limit it to the number of distinct words
k = gets.to_i
k = [k, word_counter.keys.length].min

# Sort words by descending frequency, breaking ties by alphebetical order
words_desc_freq = word_counter.sort do |a, b|
  cmp = a.last - b.last                    # .last is the count
  cmp != 0 ? -cmp : (a.first <=> b.first)  # .first is the word
end

# Output k most frequent words
(0...k).each do |i|
  puts words_desc_freq[i].first
end
```

The solution above has complexity \$O(N \log N)\$, dominated by the time it takes to sort.

Usually, when constraints are given for problems like this, it means that your program is not expected to handle input exceeding the stated limits gracefully.  It does not mean that your program needs to actively reject input that exceeds those limits.  In any case, your "validation" isn't quite right: [in Ruby, 0 is treated as a true value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10387515/1157100).

Your code is formatted reasonably well.  I would just note that the line that performs the sort is long and should be broken up.  One-line blocks are typically written using braces, like `(0..size).each { |j| count += 1 if a[i] == a[j] }`

Comment: A few points: 1. you can define the hash more simply as `word_counter = Hash.new(0)`; 2. I think it should be `{ word_counter[gets.chomp] += 1 }`; 3. `.keys` is not needed in `word_counter.keys.length`; and 4. you could use `wc.sort_by { |k,v| [-v,k] }`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has already been reviewed. Regarding readability, I'd add that a serious problem is that you have a block of code that uses almost no abstractions: every task you perform, it's done with low-level imperative code. You should use existing abstractions. And if the abstraction does not exist, write it.

I'd write:

```
# See http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rubyworks/facets/Enumerable  
module Enumerable
  def frequency
    Hash.new(0).tap { |f| each { |v| f[v] += 1 } }
  end
end

nterms = $stdin.readline.to_i
terms = $stdin.each_line.take(nterms).map(&:strip)
nfreq_terms = $stdin.readline.to_i
sorted_terms = terms.frequency.sort_by { |term, count| -count }
freq_terms = sorted_terms.take(nfreq_terms).map(&:first)
puts(freq_terms.join("\n"))
```

Note that you can read the code out loud, it describes what it's doing instead of how it's doing it. That's the goal of declarative programming.